# Heatmap on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit, parse-platform

Im really new to iOS and C in general, so forgive me if this is an daft question.

Im making an iOS app, and one of the views is a MapKit view. Im using Parse.com to deliver lat/lng's to the app, and then want all these coords (say 3000 of them), translated into a HeatMap over the standard iOS MapKit map.

So, I would like a plugin, that I can feed coords, and an array of colours, then it paints/overlays it for me. I have found this [heatmap demo](https://github.com/ryanolsonk/HeatMapDemo) but it seems to run on a CSV file.

I'm sure this can be done natively in iOS7 using clever overlay type things, but as I'm such a novice, i think a plugin would be the way for me to go :/

Thanks for the help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your link look what you are looking for. you don't have to deal with CSV, the data is an NSDictionary (cf HeatMap.h + description of the project). If the colors are not fine with you (based on MATLAB as describe in the comments) have a look to HeatMapView.m -> colorForValue:

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I can change the colours fine, but having some trouble with the NSDictionary. Do I create a new one? With some kind of for loop?

Comment: Yes ! see how it's done in HeatMapExample/HeatMapViewController.m check both function `- (void)viewDidLoad` (He create the overlay) and  `- (NSDictionary *)heatMapData` (where he create the dictionary).

Comment: So replace the bits in this loop, and ignore the rest?

`for (NSArray *line in csvContent) {}`

Also, the for loop will iterate over my parse.com data.

Thanks for the help, feel like im getting somewhere at last! :)

Comment: don't forget, the dictionary is like this : coord(lat/long)->count